# How to add custom space in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

How can I add extra space between two specfied sections in the TOC?

i.e. I want to add space only at the arrow:

[image]

Is this even possible in a simple way?

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Sec 1}
\section{Sec 2} % I want space between section 2 and 3 in the table of contents
\section{Sec 3}
\section{Sec 4}
\section{Sec 5}

\end{document}
```

(I am also using the `classicthesis` template if that makes a difference)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In your MWE you are using `article` and not `classicthesis` ;-) Happened that accidentally?

Comment: No, but I assume the solution would be the same? I just want to edit the TOC.

Comment: `\section{Sec 2}` `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1cm}}` `\section{Sec 3}` and compile twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I used the optional argument of `\section`, to make the toc entry have a blank line stacked under it.  The only thing you need to pay attention to is that if the entry is long enough to wrap in the toc, just stack under the last word of the entry, rather than under the whole entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\stacktype{L}
\tableofcontents

\section{Sec 1}
\section[\stackunder{Sec 2}{}]{Sec 2} % I want space between section 2 and 3 in the table of contents
\section{Sec 3}
\section{Sec 4}
\section{Sec 5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt using `patchcmd` from `etoolbox` with a conditional check whether chapter 3 and section 2 is reached.  Note: to increase space bwteen 1 and 2, one needs to use the last section number, i.e., 2 in this demonstration. Need compile twice for the proper redering.

```
\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}%
{\ifnum\value{chapter}=3 \ifnum\value{section}=2 % Adjust parameters for various output.
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20pt}}    % adjust 20pt to suit one's need.
\else
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{0pt}}
\fi
\fi}
{}{}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}%
{\ifnum\value{chapter}=3 \ifnum\value{section}=2
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20pt}}   % adjust 20pt to suit one's need.
\else
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{0pt}}
\fi
\fi}
{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{A section} 

\chapter{A chapter}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{A section} % I want space between section 2 and 3 
\section{A section}
\section{A section}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}  
\subsection{A subsection}

\chapter{A chapter}

\end{document}
```